# Тренировка по будням или тренировки по будням

Tags: склонение

Как правильно написать в расписании
Тренировка в будни
Тренировка по будням

Comment: Название вопроса не соответствует содержанию вопроса: тренировка/тренировки, по будням/в будни. Исправьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: И так и так правильно.

Answer (score 0):

мне кажется, есть небольшая разница, по будням или в будни.

По будням - когда речь идет о каком-то свойстве, признаке предмета:

> [что на ней по будням было ситцевое платье всегда одно...](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CkoqIQoICBAQChgyIAoQBSAAKKLI8ezz0/oCQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCHgocChoKA3JlcRITChHQv9C%2BINCx0YPQtNC90Y/QvDAB#:%7E:text=%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BC%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE)

На ней по будням - платье ситцевое.

> [по будням утро за работою](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CkoqIQoICBAQChgyIAoQBSAAKKLI8ezz0/oCQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCHgocChoKA3JlcRITChHQv9C%2BINCx0YPQtNC90Y/QvDAB#:%7E:text=%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BC%20%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8E)

По будням - ПО определяет особенность поведения:

> [..определив ей носить темно-коричневый по будням капот с мелкими оборками и красную кашемировскую шаль в день Светлого Воскресенья и своих именин..](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CkoqIQoICBAQChgyIAoQBSAAKKLI8ezz0/oCQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCHgocChoKA3JlcRITChHQv9C%2BINCx0YPQtNC90Y/QvDAB#:%7E:text=%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%20%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%2D%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BC%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D1%81%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%8E%20%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%20%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D0%92%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%2C)  Н. В. Гоголь. Иван Федорович Шпонька и его тетушка (1831-1832)

В будни - "В" конкретизация действия связанная с целью.

> [В будни ходил он в плисовой куртке, по праздникам надевал сертук из сукна домашней работы..](https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=Cj0qGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQFCGgoYChYKA3JlcRIPCg3QsiDQsdGD0LTQvdC4MAE=#:%7E:text=%D0%92%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BB%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BA%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B) А. С. Пушкин. Барышня-крестьянка (1830)

В будни он ходил в плисовой куртке(чтобы не замараться), по праздникам (когда цели одевать что-то конкретное не было) надевал сертук из сукна домашней работы.

Тут еще примечательно, как Пушкин написал "сертук домашней работы", чем очень ненавязчиво, но жирно подчеркнул **дом** и **работа**, в будни он - работал, а по праздникам был дома.

Из этого вывод:

У меня тренировка(в какой день?) в будни, - тренировка завтра, в будни, в конкретные дни/день. Главное слово *в будни*. В будни - занято.

Но, у меня тренировки по будням или по будням у меня тренировки, - главное слово *тренировки*, а по будням дополнение лишённое конкретизации, почти наречие. Я тренируюсь(как? когда?) по будням.

В будни тренировки - тоже, наверное, допустимо в ряде случаев. Но тренировка по будням - мне кажется, уже криво.